# getting attributes from xml of specyfic grand-child attributes in c#

Tags: c#, xml

Helo Every one!
I have XML file with thousands of "objects" like this:

```
<object>
    Name = "NAME TO GET"
    Type = "SPECYFIC TYPE"
    <Object.Properties>
         <Property
             Name = "firstPropertyName"
             Type = "first property Type"
             <property.Value>
                 <Arrray
                      <x:Object
                          x:Type="Some type"
                          x:Value="unimpoerantValue" />
                        <x:Object
                          x:Type="Some type 2 "
                          x:Value="IMPORTANTVALUE" />
                 />
             </property.Value>
         />                             
    </Object.Properties>
</object>
```

I need to:
-get name of the object ("NAME TO GET" in this case)
-if this object has certain Type ("SPECYFIC TYPE" in this case)
-and if inside an array there is an object with certain value ("IMPORTANTVALUE" in this case).
It can't be done just by xPath (I think), because these objects are inserted in irregular way. However construction of object itself is always the same.
I have lots of xml's with thousands of lines each. It is not possible to show them to you.
Some scrap of original file:

```
            <x:Property
          x:Name="SwimmingPool">
          <x:Property.Value>
            <x:Object
              x:Type="{pref_-720203267:SwimmingPoolEntity}">
              <x:Object.Properties>
                <x:Property
                  x:Name="activationKey"
                  x:Type="{pref_1818327951:Guid}"
                  x:Value="eb8db727-e201-44bc-989f-4f21d55bb130" />
              </x:Object.Properties>
            </x:Object>
          </x:Property.Value>
        </x:Property>
```

Comment: Is there a typo? Name is not an attribute. It is in the content of the tag.

Comment: I see there are some more mistakes in the file. Use a validator to see them. E.g.: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/?L=2

Comment: If this file were to be valid XML it should be possible to use XPath to retrieve the object names for that condition `//object[@Type='SPECIFIC TYPE' and ./Object.Properties/Property/Property.Value/Arrray/x:Object/x:Type='IMPORTANTVALUE']/@name`. If the text contains invalid XML like the text you posted I would treat it like text and use a carefully crafted regular expression instead.

Comment: you are right Sammy, I called it wrong. Also the mistake in xml has been corrected.

Comment: Dear Arkadiusz, there are many other mistakes in the xml you posted which have not been corrected. Self closing tags like `<property />`, for example, cannot contain childnodes. If your massive file indeed contains such text you are better of treating it as text instead of xml.

Comment: XML is still invalid.  Upload to http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will see `Line 8: Col 14 Element type "Property" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`

Comment: It really look like this. I pasted some property by editiing. Do you think I should treat it as a text file, instead of xml? I had few LINQ to xml queries that worked on that files.

Comment: The scrap of the original XML looks valid, in which case an XPath query should be possible. The posted scrap however does not contain enough information to construct an XPath for the requirement you explained. Try to revise your example xml to match the scrap of the original xml and you might attract an answer you were hoping for.

Comment: Structure of "tree of nodes" is irregular. That is why I can't use xPath to get all of the elements.